# Кодирование два раза

Tags: java, криптография

Здраствуйте, есть метод, он получает input и кодирует текст один раз, нужно, чтобы он кодировал два раза( то есть кодированный в Виженера текст кодировал еще раз в Виженера). Как это лучше реализовать?

```
class VigenereCodec implements Decoder, Encoder {
    private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    private static final String KEY = "AB";


    public String encode(String input) {
        StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();
        input = input.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char symbol = input.charAt(i);
            char keySymbol = KEY.charAt(j);
            int newIndex = (ALPHABET.indexOf(symbol) + ALPHABET.indexOf(keySymbol)) % ALPHABET.length();
            char newSymbol = ALPHABET.charAt(newIndex);
            letters.append(newSymbol);
            j = ++j % KEY.length();
        }
        return letters.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
```

}

Comment: Вызвать метод два раза?

Comment: не, скорее нужно, чтобы метод сработал 2 раза на один input. То есть, есть у меня input ( текст пользователя), с него  при кодировании получается encodedInput, а потом encodedInput кодируется еще раз в шифром Виженера.

Comment: Мне кажется, или у вас при вызове во второй раз получите исходную строку -- алгоритм симметричный и один и тот же ключ шифрует и расшифровывает

Answer (score 0):

А что так разве не работает?

```
String doubleEncoded=encode(encode(input));
```

Comment: спасибо, подобным образом и было сделано, но преподаватель хочет, чтобы все делалось внутри только этого метода( так как программа сделана при помощи фабричного метода, у меня есть enum vigenere2x)

Comment: @Daeris сделайте цикл на 2 повторения внутри метода. Делов то :)

Comment: вот с этим как раз то и проблемка - не могу понять как его правильно сделать, только учусь =)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо,сделал вот так, заработало

```
public String encode(String input) {
        StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder letters1 = new StringBuilder();
        input = input.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char symbol = input.charAt(i);
            char keySymbol = KEY.charAt(j);
            int newIndex = (ALPHABET.indexOf(symbol) + ALPHABET.indexOf(keySymbol)) % ALPHABET.length();
            char newSymbol = ALPHABET.charAt(newIndex);
            letters.append(newSymbol);
            char symbol1 = letters.charAt(i);
            char keySymbol1 = KEY.charAt(j);
            int newIndex1 = (ALPHABET.indexOf(symbol1) + ALPHABET.indexOf(keySymbol1)) % ALPHABET.length();
            char newSymbol1 = ALPHABET.charAt(newIndex1);
            letters1.append(newSymbol1);
            j = ++j % KEY.length();
        }

        return letters1.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
```